# How to work with leading zeros in integers

Tags: ruby, string, integer, octal

What is the proper way to deal with leading zeros in Ruby?

```
0112.to_s
 => "74"
0112.to_i
 => 74
```

Why is it converting `0112` into `74`?

How can convert `0112` to a string `"0112"` ?

---

I want to define a method that takes integer as a argument and returns it with its digits in descending order.

But this does not seem to work for me when I have leading zeros:

```rb
def descending_order(n)
  n.to_s.reverse.to_i
end
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A numeric literal that starts with `0` is an octal representation, except the literals that start with `0x` which represent hexadecimal numbers or `0b` which represent binary numbers.

```
1 * 8**2 + 1 * 8**1 + 2 * 8**0 == 74
```

To convert it to `0112`, use [`String#%`](http://ruby-doc.org//core/String.html#method-i-25) or [`Kernel#sprintf`](http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.2.0/Kernel.html#method-i-sprintf) with an appropriate format string:

```
'0%o' % 0112  # 0: leading zero, %o: represent as an octal
# => "0112"
```

Comment: that was fast and very tru!

Comment: @falsetru thanks for the fast response. How can i take this into account for a method that wants to reverse a number so that it is in descending order?

Comment: @JoelL, Do you mean something like this? `'0112'.chars.sort.reverse.join`. If so, convert the number to the string using the way given in the answer, then `the_string_object.chars.sort.reverse.join.to_i`

Comment: @falsetru i want to be able to put any number into the method above and have it reverse the number. So for example `descending_order(0112)` and have it return 2110

Comment: @JoelL, Depending on your need, you can simply: `the_string_object.reverse` (unless you meant sorting digits)

Comment: @JoelL, Please re-read my answer. `0112 == 74 == 0x4a == 0b1001010`. You'd better to use string instead of number.

Comment: @falsetru im sorry. I am not sure i worded it properly. I want to take any integer and  return it with it's digits in descending order. Even if it has leasing zeros. Thanks again

Comment: @JoelL, `('0%o' % number).reverse` or ``('0%o' % number).reverse.to_i`, these will only work if use passed octal representation. And the second one will effectively remove the trailing zeros from the original number.

Comment: @JoelL, called function cannot know how the caller called (with octal, decimal, ....)

Comment: @JoelL, In other word, as a called, the function cannot distinguish 0112,  74, 0x4a, 0b1001010. They are all same value after all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71037/discussion-between-joell-and-falsetru).

Answer (score 7):

You can't, because Ruby's `Integer` class does not store leading zeros.

A leading `0` in a *number literal* is interpreted as a prefix:

- `0` and `0o`: octal number
- `0x`: hexadecimal number
- `0b`: binary number
- `0d`: decimal number

It allows you to *enter* numbers in these bases. Ruby's parser converts the literals to the appropriate `Integer` instances. The prefix or leading zeros are discarded.

Another example is `%w` for entering arrays:

```
ary = %w(foo bar baz)
#=> ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

There's no way to get that `%w` from `ary`. The parser turns the literal into an array instance, so the script never sees the literal.

`0112` (or `0o112`) is interpreted (by the parser) as the octal number 112 and turned into the integer `74`.

A decimal 0112 is just `112`, no matter how many zeros you put in front:

```
0d0112   #=> 112
0d00112  #=> 112
0d000112 #=> 112
```

It's like additional trailing zeros for floats:

```
1.0   #=> 1.0
1.00  #=> 1.0
1.000 #=> 1.0
```

You probably have to use a string, i.e. `"0112"`

Another option is to provide the (minimum) width explicitly, e.g.:

```
def descending_order(number, width = 0)
  sprintf('%0*d', width, number).reverse.to_i
end

descending_order(123, 4)
#=> 3210

descending_order(123, 10)
#=> 3210000000
```

Comment: "Integers in Ruby don't have leading zeros" I'm not sure that's the right way to say it. Integers can be represented in octal notation with a leading `0`. The default representation is in decimal though.

Comment: @Stefan thanks for your response. Is it possible to define a method that takes any integer and just returns the numbers in descending order without knowing how many digits it contains?

Comment: @JoelL no, reversing 321000 gives 123, the zeros are lost. Ruby's `Integer` class can't store leading zeros.

Comment: @theTinMan thanks, I've changed the sentence. I wanted to point out that there's a difference between the number literal and the `Integer` instance.

Comment: Ah, yes, definitely there is a difference between the literal and the Integer.

Comment: @JoelL, What I think you're not understanding is that Ruby sees `0123` and turns it into `83` before the script gains control. You *can't* type in literal values in octal notation and access them as anything but an Integer, which, at that point is too late for what you want. Instead, you MUST use some form of string representation which will not be converted. `'0123'.reverse # => "3210"` for instance.

Comment: That intermediate step is one that catches all of us at least once.