# Only string (not number) quoting when generating CSV

Tags: ruby, csv

I generate CSV data as follows:

```
require 'csv'
CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << ['a', 123, 1.5, '0123']
end
```

This returns this result:

```
"a,123,1.5,0123\n"
```

The problem is that Excel will interpret `0123` as integer. On the other side, when using `force_quotes: true`, the values `123` and `1.5` won't be interpreted as numbers anymore.

How can I quote only strings, not numbers, to get the following result?

```
"\"a\",123,1.5,\"0123\"\n"
```

Comment: This post might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28545559/how-to-work-with-leading-zeros-in-integers

Comment: Thanks, but this is actually not my problem. ```'0123'``` already is a string and I want it to be quoted as such, in contrast to ```123``` or ```1.5``` which should not be quoted.

Comment: Are you certain that your stated result is valid CSV? I cannot get it to validate at csvlint.io

Comment: See this post for more information: http://superuser.com/questions/318420/formatting-a-comma-delimited-csv-to-force-excel-to-interpret-value-as-a-string

Comment: I saw that http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values features examples with both quoted _and_ unquoted values.

Answer (score 0):

```
require 'csv'
test = CSV.generate do |csv|
  csv << ['a', 123, 1.5, '0123'].map{|e|e.class == String ? "\"#{e}\"" : e}
end
puts test # => """a""",123,1.5,"""0123"""
```

This output is valid CSV and gets imported into spreadsheets as:

```
A1: "a"
B1: 123
C1: 1.5
D1: "0123"
```

Is this what you are looking for?

---

Edit:

In case it wasn't obvious, what I'm doing here is checking each value before I pass it into the csv. If it's a string, surround it with quotes (the `\"` is the escaped quote) and then let CSV escape them however it needs to in order to be valid.

Regardless of the method you are using to pass things into your csv object, you should be able to do the same check and modify the strings that way.

Alternatively if you have access to the source data, add the surrounding quotes there.

Comment: Alright, you'd have to manually escape quotes in these strings then, as it could be ```'a "b" c'```. And maybe also better use ```is_a?``` to compare the classes?

Comment: You don't need to manually escape internal quotes, csv will do it for you. And yes, `is_a?` is better for class checking, I just wasn't thinking.

Comment: So to confirm, `csv << ['a "b" c']` will get imported into excel as `"a "b" c"` if you pass it through the test above

Comment: There is one more problem, as I don't want to have the quotes in the Excel rows. Right now, with three quotes, the string value is displayed as ```"a"``` in the cell.

Comment: You will need to specify to excel how you want to read values in, then. There is no way to encode the fact that `0123` is a string and not a number without adding characters to the CSV. The superuser post I linked to above shows you how to specify data type during file opening.

Comment: It would work if there's the value ```"0123"``` (only one double quote) in the CSV. Then the option "Quoted field as text" might be used when opening the CSV. But as it seems, this is not possible to achieve without extending the CSV generator...?