# Why does `Integer('009')` not work, but `Float('009')` does?

Tags: ruby, literals

I got the following output in the ruby console.

```
Integer('009') # => ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "009"
```

But if I try the convert the same string into `Float`, it works.

```
Float('009') # => 9.0
```

Why does `Float` convert this while `Integer` does not?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to work with leading zeros in integers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28545559/how-to-work-with-leading-zeros-in-integers)

Comment: This answer deal with Integer parsing in various bases (in this case, octal). Floats are always represented in Base 10 and thus don't exhibit this behaviour.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Kernel#Integer](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer) interprets arguments starting with a leading `0` as octal. Because the [octal number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal) ony uses digits `0-7`, a number containing a `9` is not defined. From the documentation:

> If arg is a String, when base is omitted or equals zero, radix indicators (0, 0b, and 0x) are honored.

[Kernel#Float](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Kernel.html#method-i-Float), on the other hand, does not behave this way.

---

To convert `"009"` to an integer in base 10 using `Integer`, you need to pass an optional argument specifying the base:

```
Integer("009", 10)
```

Comment: unexpected this is. `'009'.to_i` behavior I expected by default. Over-engineered this feels.

Answer (score 5):

As per [docs](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ruby-doc-bundle/Manual/man-1.4/function.html#Integer)

> Converts the argument to the integer value. If the argument is string,
>   and happen to start with 0x, 0b, 0, interprets it as hex, binary,
>   octal string respectively.

Since `009` is interpreted as octal you are getting error.

Alternatively you can also do:

```
'009'.to_i
#=> 9
```